# Configuring WiFi drive on MacBook Air running Kali Linux

Tags: linux, boot, wifi, kali-linux, broadcom

I installed Kali Linux 2.0 recently, and am trying to make the WiFi work. I was following [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/wl#Broadcom_BCM4311.2C_BCM4312.2C_BCM4313.2C_BCM4321.2C_BCM4322.2C_BCM43224.2C_BCM43225.2C_BCM43227.2C_BCM43228.2C_BCM43142.2C_BCM4331.2C_BCM4352.2C_BCM4360_devices_.28wl.29). However, when I get to the 4th step, I get this:

```
root@KaliDark:~# modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma

root@KaliDark:~# modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
```

Any ideas on how to go around this?
It's the last step I think, to making this thing work.

I installed Kali Linux 2.0, on MacBook Air (El Capitan 10.11.1). And I have a Broadcom chip BCM4360 the a0 module, one that works with Debian.

Comment: The error message indicates the `wl` kernel module was not installed properly. The instructions you're following are for Debian current stable, not for Debian testing which Kali is apparently based on. Please run `apt-cache policy broadcom-sta-dkms` and `dkms status` to see if the kernel module sources are present and ready for compilation, and edit the outputs into your question. Then read `/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/kernel-$(uname -r)/log/make.log` to see the error messages occurred during the module compilation attempt.